# ol.source.MapQuest is not a constructor

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, mapquest

While adding OSM Mapquest satellite map to the openlayers3 i'm getting an error as follow "ol.source.MapQuest is not a constructor".
The sample code is as follows

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Satellite Map</title> </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../java_scripts/v3.17.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../ccs/layer_switcher.css" />
  <script src="../java_scripts/self/layer_switcher.js"></script>
    <div id="map" class="map" style="width:50%;height:50%" ></div>

    <script>        
      var osm= new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'OSM',
            //type: 'base',
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          });         
          var sat=new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'MapQuest Satellite',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
                });

var india_source=new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/satya/wms',
params: {LAYERS: 'satya:districts_2011census'},
serverType: 'geoserver'});         
 var india = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'India',
            //type: 'base',
            visible: false,
            source:india_source
          });         
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [osm,india,sat],
        target: 'map',
        projection:'EPSG:4326',
        view:new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [79.419,15.428],
          zoom: 5
        }),

      });

      var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'satya' // Optional label for button
    }); 
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);  
      map.addLayer(osm);
      map.addLayer(india);
      map.addLayer(sat);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If i remove sat layer the osm map is comming. Please help me to resolve..

Comment: so what shall i do? what shall i write there, when not MapQuest :( i didnt get it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MapQuest got removed because of their changes, see upgrade notes here https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.17.0

ol.source.MapQuest removal

Because of changes at MapQuest (see: https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk/2016-June/076106.html) we had to remove the MapQuest source for now (see #5484 for details).

Comment: Then how to add satellite data from opensource in openlayers3?

Comment: You can use e.g.:https://gist.github.com/bartvde/773da09549ee911959e41e6131e7a340